# Shipping JRE 8 Early Access Releases

Tags: bundle, java, java-8

I used jdk8 to compile my java program to use some latest  feature.

Can JRE 8 be shipped before final release ? 
Looks like JRE 8 is not available standalone.So can I ship JDK8 before it it's final release

Comment: how did you notice JRE 8 was not available standalone?

Comment: @panny What I meant is that the only downloadable available now is JDK8 from http://jdk8.java.net/download.html . I did not find JRE8 as downloadable like JRE7 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jre-7-download-432155.html) . Of course one can take the JRE directory from a JDK8 installation directory but not sure if it legal to distribute .

Answer (score 0):

JRE8 and JDK8 are currently in Early Adopter version (EA). It's license terms follow: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/ea-license-152003.html

> We grant You a revocable, nonexclusive, nontransferable, royalty-free and limited right to (a) use one (1) copy of the binary portions of the Programs and any Supplemental Programs for the sole purpose of internal non-production and non-commercial evaluation and testing of the Programs, including, developing no more than a single prototype of each of Your applications;

Now, of course, I'm no lawyer nor is this legal advice, but as this says, you can't ship a jre8 software (as that would include binary portions of jre8) to your production or commercial non-evaluation nor testing multiple non-prototypes of your application.

Additionally, you'd be subject to their Export Controls, found in the above address.

Answer (score 0):

The GA is available as of March 18th:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html